# Error pushing package to Octopus Deploy from build script

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

As part of our TFS build I'm trying to push the latest package from our build pipeline to our **Octopus Deploy** instance. However I'm getting the following error.

[image]

I'm using a script task to execute the following `octo push` command.

```
octo push --package=mypackage.nupkg --overwrite-mode=OverwriteExisting --server=https://mycompany.octopus.app --user=myname@mycompany.com --pass=mypassword --debug --LogLevel=debug
```

Any ideas what's causing the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks attempting to log in to the Octopus server using a username and password, but your instance isn't configured to accept that authentication type.

Is this pipeline pushing to an Octopus Cloud instance? If so, your authentication is via OctopusID, an external auth provider, rather than a username/password account on the Octopus instance itself.

As a general rule, using [an API key](https://octopus.com/docs/octopus-rest-api/how-to-create-an-api-key) is the recommended approach here, rather than username/password authentication.

Comment: You've also replied to me on the Octopus forum. I'll mark this as answer. Thanks :)